# Adding multiple buttons to JFrame, text+color not showing up

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm trying to add 10 buttons to a `JPanel` one by one, and then adding them all to a `JFrame`. I need to have my for loop because it has to be easy changing the number of buttons. All the buttons also need to have different colors and texts (I know that they CAN get the same color with the code below, but that's OK for now).

My output from the code below is just a frame with 10 white buttons and no text/color. Why is the `colors`, `text` and the `actionlistener` not getting connected to my buttons?

I've read on other questions that I have to be careful of my placements regarding `frame.add(panel`, `frame.pack()` and `frame.setVisible(true)`, but I think these are correctly placed outside of my `forloop`. I also tried using `frame.setContentPane(panel)`, but this gave the same result - a frame with 10 white buttons and no text/color.

`CMain class`:

```
public class CMain extends MyButton {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int numberofbuttons = 10;

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyButton testing");

    for (int i = 0; i < numberofbuttons; i++) {

        float r = randomGenerator.nextFloat();float g = randomGenerator.nextFloat();float b = randomGenerator.nextFloat();float r2 = randomGenerator.nextFloat();float g2 = randomGenerator.nextFloat();float b2 = randomGenerator.nextFloat();

        String theText = "SWITCH ME BACK";
        String theOtherText = "button nr: " + i;
        Color theColor = new Color(r, g, b);
        Color theOtherColor = new Color(r2, g2, b2);

        MyButton myb = new MyButton(theColor, theOtherColor, theText, theOtherText);
        panel.add(myb);
    }
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

`MyButton class`:

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

private JButton button;
private Color col1;
private Color col2;
private String text1;
private String text2;

public MyButton(Color col1, Color col2, String text1, String text2) {
    this.col1 = col1;
    this.col2 = col2;
    this.text1 = text1;
    this.text2 = text2;
    button = new JButton(text1);
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.setBackground(col1);
    button.addActionListener(this);
}

public MyButton() {
    this(Color.blue, Color.red, "click = make red", "click = reset to blue");
}

public void ToggleState() {
    Color initialBackground = button.getBackground();

    if (initialBackground == col1) {
        button.setBackground(col2);
        button.setText(text2);
    } else if (initialBackground == col2) {
        button.setBackground(col1);
        button.setText(text1);
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == button) {
        this.ToggleState();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating two JButtons with your class, one the object of the class itself (the `this` if you will) and the second, the `button` `JButton` variable within the class:

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {  // **** this is a JButton

    private JButton button; // ***** and so is THIS!
```

Get rid of the `button` variable and only work with `this` and your problems will likely be fixed.

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {  // this is a JButton

    // private JButton button; // get rid of this
    // and then change all code where you try to use button to this.
```

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    // private JButton button;
    private Color col1;
    private Color col2;
    private String text1;
    private String text2;

    public MyButton(Color col1, Color col2, String text1, String text2) {

        super(text1);   // *********** also add this **********

        this.col1 = col1;
        this.col2 = col2;
        this.text1 = text1;
        this.text2 = text2;
        // button = new JButton(text1);
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setBackground(col1);
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public MyButton() {
        this(Color.blue, Color.red, "click = make red", "click = reset to blue");
    }

    public void ToggleState() {
        Color initialBackground = this.getBackground();

        if (initialBackground == col1) {
            this.setBackground(col2);
            this.setText(text2);
        } else if (initialBackground == col2) {
            this.setBackground(col1);
            this.setText(text1);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // if (e.getSource() == button) {
        this.ToggleState();
        // }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm getting all colors/texts. One thing though, the text only appears after I press the button, is this possible to fix?

Comment: @armara: new problem, new question.

Comment: @armara: you need to pass text1 into `this` as well. Either with `super(text`)` in the constructor's first line or via `setText(...)`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll post a new Q if needed. You can delete this comment aswell. :)

Comment: @armara: other issue: CMain should definitely **not** extend MyButton. This is a misuse of inheritance and could prove dangerous later. Myself, I wouldn't even have MyButton extend JButton, but would have it use composition (your code tries to use **both**, and that is worse than using either).

Comment: @armara: no need for a new question as the second problem is trivial and has been solved.

Comment: @HovercraftFoE I hadn't even thought about that, thanks! `CMain` is no longer extending `MyButton`, the code is working anyway. I will still extend `MyButton` with `JButton` because the assignment requests it, but I'll remember this for the future.

Comment: @armara: nice [mcve] with your question by the way. 1+ for that.